# Remove default menu controls

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I have a vertical layout group filled with UI buttons used as menus in my game.  They work well for mousing over and clicking, and I am in the process of adding keyboard controls.

The issue I have is that there appears to be a default control mechanism that moves the selection when pressing Up or Down on the keyboard, so when I add my own, the two are fighting each other.  I don't want this.  How can I tell Unity to just allow me to handle the keyboard inputs for these menus?

Comment: Can you show us how you've configured the EventSystem object in your scene, and its Standalone Input Module or equivalent?

Comment: The EventSystem object indeed had a default actions asset.  I've switched that to my input actions asset and can move forward. THANK YOU!

Comment: Want to document your solution as an Answer below, to help other developers encountering similar problems?

Answer (score 2):

Your EventSystem has an "Input System UI Input Module" attached to it, which has a default Actions Asset linked to it.  This is where the extra menu movements are coming from.

One solution is to change the Move option under Action Assets to NONE.  This will remove the impact that pressing Up / Down has on menu selection here, while keeping the other pieces of this input you may depend on (mouse position etc..)